# Passing array to method in C#

Tags: c#

I guess it's rather stupid question.
I want to pass an array argument to method by value, not by link, i.e. I want to make a copy of object to prevent changing of argument inside the method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing the argument is never a problem, that doesn't propagate back.  Only changing the array content.

Answer (score 8):

If your method acts destructively on its parameter's contents, simply make a copy of the array inside the method.

This is as simple as

```
var copy = parameter.ToArray();
```

if you are using LINQ, otherwise it can also be done easily with [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx).

This is much better than copying *before* calling the method (as you mention in the question), because you can always forget to do that. Copying *inside* the method leaves no possibility of error.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are reference types. You can't have them automatically be cloned when passed to a method.

You have to make a clone manually and pass the resulting array to the method:

```
int[] array = ...

MyMethod((int[])array.Clone());
```

Note that this is an *O(n)* operation can can be quite slow for large arrays or many repeated calls.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in C#.  You will need to copy the array yourself, either inside the method, or on the calling side:

```
int[] array = GetIntArray();
CallSomeMethod(array.ToArray()); // ToArray() makes a copy of the input...
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question in the OP is the poster is looking for a way to pass a reference type by value.  I found this example:

```
class PassingRefByVal 
{
   static void Change(int[] arr)
   {
      //arr[0]=888;   // This change affects the original element.
      arr = new int[5] {-3, -1, -2, -3, -4};   // This change is local.
      Console.WriteLine("Inside the method, the first element is: {0}", arr[0]);
   }

   public static void Main() 
   {
      int[] myArray = {1,4,5};
      Console.WriteLine("Inside Main, before calling the method, the first element is: {0}", myArray [0]);
      Change(myArray);
      Console.WriteLine("Inside Main, after calling the method, the first element is: {0}", myArray [0]);
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Isn't that just the standard way of passing an array argument?